# Evaluate a math expression

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm not sure if this is possible without a stored procedure, but I'm hoping it's possible:

I have a column in my database that stores information like `3 < x < 5` or `20 >= x >= 10`, etc etc. My need is to evaluate whether the expression is true if we plug a # into `x`.

Currently, I'm using a combination of regex & eval to determine if an expression is true, like the following:

```
$evalExpression = '3<x<5';
$evalValue = 4;

preg_match("#^(.*?)(<=|>=|<|>)(.*?)(<=|>=|<|>)(.*?)$#", $evalExpression, $evalPieces);

if (eval("return {$range_pieces[1]} {$range_pieces[2]} $response && $response {$range_pieces[4]} {$range_pieces[5]};")) {
    return true;
}
```

However, I am trying to figure out a way where I can accomplish this with SQL(MySQL) alone.  For instance:

```
SELECT 3 < 4 && 4 < 5 FROM table X
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?  Would stored procedures be necessary to accomplish something like this?  I'm sure a different database schema would make this easier, but I have inherited this structure, and am trying to figure out if my needs can be accomplished before resorting to changing the schema.

Thanks!

Comment: SQL doesn't directly support things like this. Imagine the chaos if the string you want to evaluate is 'drop table students;'. The general approach is to generate dynamic SQL instead. (Dynamic SQL has its own problems and risks, too.)

Comment: Yes Mike, I agree completely.. Definitely don't want to have an eval type statement like PHP (even if we are checking for injection).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe not the answer you are looking for but I would change the way you are storing the information here and that would make the evaluation at the database level possible...

Avoid magic strings, instead be explicit about the information in each column

```
magic_string 
------------
3 < x < 5
20 >= x >= 10
```

Might become

```
upper_bound | ub_inclusive | lower_bound | lb_inclusive
------------|--------------|-------------|---------------
5           |N             |3            |N
20          |Y             |10           |Y
```

And your query become doable

```
SEL * FROM TABLE WHERE 
      (
         (x < upper_bound and ub_inclusive = 'N') OR 
         (x <= upper_bound and ub_inclusive = 'Y')
      ) AND (
         (x > lower_bound and lb_inclusive = 'N') OR 
         (x >= lower_bound and lb_inclusive = 'Y')
      )
```

*Here's an optimized version of the same query

```
SEL * FROM TABLE WHERE 
      (
         (x < upper_bound ) OR (x = upper_bound and ub_inclusive = 'Y')
      ) AND (
         (x > lower_bound ) OR (x = lower_bound and lb_inclusive = 'Y')
      )
```

Comment: I like your inclusive boolean idea. It is cleaner than my suggestion.

Comment: @gbtimmon: This is beautiful.  Obviously requires schema changes, but I had a feeling this was necessary anyway.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you model your rules tables with seperate columns for each type of check, with each 
column being a number datatype, which allow NULLS where that rule doesn't apply.

For example

```
CREATE TABLE RULES
(   RULE,ID
    ,EQUAL
    ,GREATER_THAN
    ,GREAR_THAN_EQUAL
    ,LESS_THAN
    ,LESS_THAN_EQUAL
)
```

Your First example above `3 < x < 5` would be
`1|NULL|3|NULL|5|NULL`

Comment: Your second example `20 >= x >= 10' would be `1|NULL|NULL|10|NULL|20`

Comment: Thank you Declan.  Your answer works as well, but I feel like gbtimmon's is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

From a purely syntactic prespective, you can do things like this:

```sql
SELECT 3 < 4 && 4 < 5; -- echoes 1 (true)
SET @s = 'SELECT 3<4'; PREPARE stmt FROM @s; EXECUTE stmt; -- echoes 1 (true)
```

Notice you can build `@s` dynamically.

However I strongly concur with gbtimmon's advice (ie. avoid magic strings).